# Remove and seal up old air vents

Tags: insulation, ventilation, sound-proofing

I recently bought an apartment and have now realised that there are 4 old air vents in the flat that let cold air and noise in. The flat is right outside a restaurant and a pub and it gets super noisy in the summer, and then really cold in the winter. I didn't realise these vents were there when checking out the apartment as the window blinds cleverly covered them (lesson learned). Now, I want to see what my options are for sealing up the old air vents. There are two in the living that are sound dampening vents (acoustic louvres)

[image: Bulky air vent in the living room]

And then more traditional air vents in the kitchen:

[image: Air vents in the kitchen]

My question is:

1. How would I go about removing and sealing up these air vents? The ones in the living room seem like the biggest challenge
2. Are there any repercussions to sealing these up from a property value stand point? Perhaps removing them is against building regulations or could affect the value of the property?

The building is from 1982 so I imagine these were installed when it was built and are now old and outdated. Any advice would be great!

Comment: what kind of heating do you have

Comment: Since they have slots, is there a piece behind that slides across to cover those slots, or does the front panel slide to do so?

Comment: None of the vents have any sliding parts.. this is what confuses me as well as there seems to be no functional way to close them. Heating is standard radiators and a CV kettle. Building from 1980s in Amsterdam

Comment: @helpme are you able to remove the vent cover and access whatever ducting may be behind it?

Comment: So I can remove the vent cover for the kitchen vents, but don't see any easy way of doing this for the big vents in the living room.. I was thinking I could seal up the kitchen vents with expanding foam, but again don't know what the solution would be for the living room vents. I've never seen these type before and was hoping someone here would have some experience with them